# responsive dropdown menu with sub menu /sidenav? dropdown menu always open and doesn't hide when i click away

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to coding and trying to create a sidenav with two dropdown menus and one link and i think there's something wrong with my javascript. the menu is displayed always open and doesn't close when  i click away or click the other dropdown

I know the code is a mess I'm sorry

```js
/* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

/* Fixed sidenav, full height */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

/* On mouse-over */
.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: pink;
}

/* Main content */
.main {
  margin-left: 200px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 20px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}


}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: none;
  padding-left: 8px;
}


/* Some media queries for responsiveness */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="sidenav">
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Projects and Exhibitions

  </button>
   <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Curatorial
 
  </button>
   <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
 
  <a href="#Information">Information</a>
</div>
```

i tried to change the id's and mess with the javascript but I really don't know what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

So I have modified your JavaScript and added an window.onload event so that the dropdown menus are closed upon loading the page. I also added a loop that checks and closes other dropdowns when you click on one...

```
<script>
// Close dropdown on page load
window.onload = function() {
var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-container");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  dropdowns[i].style.display = "none";
}
}

function removeActiveClass() {
    var activeElements = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav a.active, .sidenav .dropdown-btn.active');
    activeElements.forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.classList.remove('active');
    });
}
  
/* Loop through dropdown to show or hide */
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Close other dropdowns when one is clicked and remove their active class
    var j;
    for(j = 0; j < dropdown.length; j++) {
      if (dropdown[j] !== this && dropdown[j].nextElementSibling.style.display === "block") {
        dropdown[j].nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
      }
    }

    // Toggle clicked dropdown
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      removeActiveClass();
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
      this.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
}

var sideLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav a:not(.dropdown-btn)');
sideLinks.forEach(function(link) {
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        removeActiveClass();
        link.classList.add('active');
    });
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.closest('.sidenav')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-container");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.style.display === "block") {
                openDropdown.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        removeActiveClass();
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hey I'm trying to add an active class to the sidebar dropdown so the dropdown buttons would stay pink when the nav menu is open. I was able to get it to toggle except for when you click outside of the menu to close it, it stays active. I added  this.classList.toggle("active");  is this the right way to do it?

Comment: @thisisaboutmysink I have edited my answer and updated the JavaScript to make this work. Don't forget to add the css code: .dropdown-btn.active {color: pink;}

Comment: @thisisaboutmysink I'm sorry. I realised I made a mistake. I have edited the JavaScript code in my first answer again. And the CSS that you need to add instead of the last CSS code I gave you is: .sidenav a.active, .dropdown-btn.active {color: pink;}

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked correctly you just needed to click it twice to work because initially the container was inactive but no js was run to set the content to display none. You can either manually do this like in my answer or in an onload event like the other poster

```js
/* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}


/* Fixed sidenav, full height */

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}


/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */

.sidenav a,
.dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}


/* On mouse-over */

.sidenav a:hover,
.dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: pink;
}


/* Main content */

.main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 20px;
  /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}


}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: none;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

/* Some media queries for responsiveness */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="sidenav">
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Projects and Exhibitions</button>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Curatorial</button>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>

  <a href="#Information">Information</a>
</div>
```